# Selecting file in Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5, file-path

[image: Qt Designer in QGIS]

I want the toolbox to prompt out a file select window so that user can select the file and get the path to be used in my Plugin.

Where do I start to code since I just have:

```py
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = PalmCounterV2Dialog()

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dialog class (PalmCounterV2Dialog) you should add an action to the button with "..." in __init__. And write the method to handle the event see "select_file".

```
class PalmCounterV2Dialog(...)
    ...
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.file_select.clicked.connect(self.select_file)
        # file_select is the name of the button in Qt designer
        ...

    def select_file(self):
        qfd = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        filt = self.plugin.tr("Text files(*.txt)") # change the file type
        title = self.plugin.tr("Select a text file")
        f, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(qfd, title, ".", filt)
        # finaly put f into the text box
        self.file_name.setText(f) # file_name is the name of your text box
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done it!!